# Cannot get value req.body.value in form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**html form**

```
<form method="post" action="/login">
    <input type="text" name="user_vi" placeholder="User name vi" value="usernametest">
    <input type="text" name="email_vi" placeholder="Email vi">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="user_en" placeholder="User name en">
    <input type="text" name="email_en" placeholder="Email en">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('views', './views'); // specify the views directory
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // register the template engine
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Home page', message: 'Home there!' })
});
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { title: 'Login', message: 'Login there!' })
});
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    var lang = 'vi';
    var user_name = 'user_' + lang;
    //console.log(user_name);
    //result = "user_vi"
    console.log(req.body.user_name);
    //result = undefined
    console.log(req.body.user_vi);
    //result = 'usernametest'
    res.render('login', {
        title: 'Login',
        message: 'Login there!'
    });
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('connect port 3000');
});
var lang = 'vi';
var user_name = 'user_' + lang;
//console.log(user_name);
//result = "user_vi"
//console.log(req.body.user_vi);
//result = 'usernametest'
console.log(req.body.user_name);
//result = undefined
```

I cannot get value here (req.body.user_name). How can I get this ?

Answer (score 1):

> req.body is an object. you are accessing the key wrongly.

your body object will look like this.

```
body{
"user_vi":"value",
"email_vi:"value",
"user_en":"value",
"email_en":"value"
}
```

`req.body.user_name`   is the wrong way to access, because `user_name` is a variable, not the key. this will search body object for the key `"user_name"` which is an invalid key.

here is the correct way to access through a variable.
use `req.body[user_name]`

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong element name with `user_name` which is actually `user_en`.

Once try like `req.body.user_en`.

Give it a try, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just access the request body by key:

```
request.body[key];
```

In your case:

```
request.body[user_name];
```

Will solve the problem!